# Check Primitive Condition of Product of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Consider $n-1$ Companion matrices [$C^{(i)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)  over $\mathbb{R}$, for $1\leq i \leq n-1$, which are defined by the following form:
$$
C^{(i)}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 &1 &0 &\cdots &\cdots &0 \\
0 &0 &1 &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &0 \\
0 &\cdots &\cdots &0&0 &1 \\
u_1^{(i)} &u_2^{(i)} &u_3^{(i)} &\cdots &u_{n-1}^{(i)} &u_{n}^{(i)}
\end{array}
\right)_{n\times n}
$$
where $u_k^{(i)}$ for $1\leq i \leq n-1$ and $1\leq k \leq n$, are positive  integer numbers.

Now consider the matrix $B=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\, C^{(i)}$, the product of matrices $C^{(i)}$.

*My question:* Let $B=(b_{i,j})$. Then how to prove that $b_{1,j}=0$ for $1\leq j \leq n-1$.

for example for $n=3$ we have 
$$
B  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & b_{1,3}\\ b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3}\\ b_{3,1} & b_{3,2}& b_{3,3} \end{pmatrix}.
$$

*My try:* Consider digraphs of $C^{(i)}$ matrices . The elements $u_k^{(i)}$'s are called weight in these  digraphs. Therefore, we can assume that they have the same value which means  $u_k^{(1)}=u_k^{(2)}=\cdots=u_k^{(n-1)}$ for $1\leq k \leq n$.

Hence it is enough to prove if $E=(C^{(1)})^{n-1}=(e_{i,j})$  then why $e_{1,j}=0$ for $1\leq j \leq n-1$.
Consider digraph of $C^{(i)}$ then we can see that there is no walk of length $n-1$ from the vertex $v_1$ to $v_j$ for $1\leq j \leq n-1$ which means 
$e_{1,j}=0$ for $1\leq j \leq n-1$.

Is this proof correct? If there is other proof, I appreciate you to post it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is sorta correct, but you should justify better why you can suppose all the weights as the same.

An other proof goes through noticing that 
$$
e_i^T C^{(k)} = e_{i+1}^T$$
for every $k$ and every $i<n$, since $e_i^T C^{(k)} $ is the $i$-th row of $C^{(k)}$. Now you have
$$
b_{1j} = e_1^T B e_j = e_1^T C^{(1)} C^{(2)} \dots C^{(n-1)} e_j =
e_2^T C^{(2)} C^{(3)} \dots C^{(n-1)} e_j =$$$$
e_3^T C^{(3)} C^{(4)} \dots C^{(n-1)} e_j = 
\dots = e_{n-1}^T C^{(n-1)} e_j 
$$
and the element $(n-1,j)$ of $C^{(n-1)}$ is zero whenever $1\le j<n$.

Comment: Sorry, I inverted the indexes

Comment: Is my proof correct?

Comment: @Amin235 Yes, I've edited

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer.  Is it possible to ask you to help, how to proof by Graph theory.Thanks again

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but you should take $u = \max_{i,j} u_j^{(i)}$ and consider the matrix $C$ with $u$ instead of $u_j^{(i)}$. It is easy to see that $B\le C^{n-1}$ entry by entry, so you can repeat your reasoning for $C^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your useful hint. Excuse me that I ask too question. My last question is that is this question and its proof valid over finite field? Thanks

Comment: @Amin235 The statement is still true, and my proof holds, but the proof in Graph Theory needs a bit more justifications

Comment: You are right. Thanks for useful comments.